# Java Multidimensional array passing as a object

Tags: java, oop, object, multidimensional-array

Its just a OOP test I was doing, could you please help me understanding the concept of how to set the Multidimensional array value by passing the object. Please check the below code;

```
 public class agnts {



 private int rate[][] = new int [4][5];

 public agnts(){
 rate[0][1] = new pric(25);
 rate[1][1]=new pric(30);
 rate[2][1]= new pric(45);
 rate[3][1]=new pric(55);
 }    
 }
 class pric {
 //int pric [][]= new int [4][5];
 int pric;
public pric(int p){

    this.pric=p;
}
 public int getPric(){
    return pric;
}
}
 public static void main(String[] args) {        

  agnts tz=  new agnts();
  }
```

I get an error of type incompatible required:int found:pric 
Am I doing something wrong? please advise.

Comment: well you have an `int[][]` and your are trying to set its elements to your class `pric`. You need to do `rate[X][Y]=new pric(Z).getPric();`. Better yet, read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/).

Answer (score 2):

You're getting an error because of this

```
private int rate[][] = new int [4][5];
// You declare a multi-dimensional integer array.

public agnts(){
  // you then attempt to assign objects to that array.
  rate[0][1] = new pric(25);
  rate[1][1]=new pric(30);
  rate[2][1]= new pric(45);
  rate[3][1]=new pric(55);
}
```

you declared matrix of integers but you're initializing it with your pric class..

**UPDATE 1:**
as bmorris591 suggested at is comment:

```
 public agnts(){
     rate[0][1] = new pric(25).getPric();
     rate[1][1]=new pric(30).getPric();
     rate[2][1]= new pric(45).getPric();
     rate[3][1]=new pric(55).getPric();
  }
```

**UPDATE 2:**
if you want to set random number for the all matrix:

```
for (int row = 0; row < rate.length; row ++ )
 for (int col = 0; col < col[row].length; ; col ++)
    rate[row][col] = (int)(Math.Random()*10+1); // this will generate number between 1 to 10
```

Comment: can you please point me what I need to do to fix it any example would be very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`rate` is an array of arrays of integers:

```
private int rate[][] = new int [4][5];
```

so `rate[0][1]` is an `int`.

So, since it's an `int`, assigning it an instance of `pric` makes no sense:

```
rate[0][1] = new pric(25);
```

You might want to initialize it to an int:

```
rate[0][1] = 25;
```

Or you might want to make rate an array of arrays of pric:

```
private pric[][] rate = new pric[4][5];
```

Note that Java conventions tell that classes should start with an uppercase letter. Choosing good names makes the code more readable also. What is a `pric`? What is an `agnts`?

Answer (score 0):

You have declared an array of `int`

```
private int rate[][] = new int[4][5];
```

And you have class `pric` which *contains* an `int`.

You are trying to set members of the array to be equal to `new pric(X)`, this is the same as

```
int i = new pric(X);
```

If you cannot see what is wrong with that then maybe start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/) and work your way through.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the constructor for pric here:
    `rate[0][1]=new pric(25);`

The constructor returns an object of class pric, but you want to call getPric() on that instead:
    `rate[0][1]=new pric(25).getPric();`